# how to implement new constructor definition and normal constructor def at same time in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-generics

When we both use new constructor definition and normal constructor definition in ts, how to implement the function to make ts pass?
I try to use function to implement the definition, but it failed, ts can't understand what i am doing

```
interface Date1 {
    x: number
}
interface Date1Constructor {
    new(s: string): Date1
    (n: number): number
}
// if use class, we can't implement constructor without new

// class Date1Imple implements Date1 {
//     constructor(s:string) {
//     }
// }

// or

// if use function, how to make ts know what we are doing makes sense

// function Date1Imple(param: string): Date1;
// function Date1Imple(param: number): number; and 
// function Date1Imple(param: string | number): Date1 | number {
//     if(this){
//         if (typeof param === 'string') {
//             return {
//                 x: 2
//             }
//         }
//     }
//     if (typeof param === 'number') {
//         return 2
//     }
// }
function test(a: Date1Constructor) {
}
test(Date1Imple)
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation signature of an overloaded function is never 100% compatible with a strict interpretation of all of the overloads. Since the implementation signature isn't included in the options available at the call site, that's okay, and we can use a gentle `as Date1Constructor` at the end to say it's okay to TypeScript. As with any type assertion, though, it's important to triple-check that your logic matches the assertion you're making.

In this case, we can differentiate between a `new` call and a non-`new` call via `new.target` (in modern environments). In a `new` call, only a `string` argument is allowed; in a non-`new` call, only a `number` is allowed:

```typescript
const Date1Imple = function (param: string | number) {
    if (new.target) {
        if (typeof param !== "string") {
            throw new Error(`Invalid invocation, 'new Date1Imple(x)' requires a string argument.`);
        }
        return {
            x: 2
        };
    }
    if (typeof param !== "number") {
        throw new Error(`Invalid invocation, 'Date1Imple(x)' requires a number argument.`);
    }
    return 2;
} as Date1Constructor;
```

That produces the desired behavior and offers the desired signatures:

```typescript
// Works, typeof `dt` is `string`
const dt = new Date1Imple("x");

// Works, typeof `num` is `number`
const num = Date1Imple(42);

// Fails as expected, the `new` signature doesn't allow a `number` argument
const dt2 = new Date1Imple(42);

// Fails as expected, the non-`new` signature doesn't allow a `string` argument
const num2 = Date1Imple("42");
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJ0gRmQbwFDKHIAeAXMiAK4C2ARtANx4C+eoksiK6WAwgPYgAzmCiUEYflFwEiICAHcAFEPIiooAOYBKcjwiYmRZEpDkqdaLoo16UJqzwJBItBgMBJagAcANigBeZBhKEAlgQRNvOCg4ajVRLWQAHxtLKG0ZY2AYE3kFADowGM0IMEz8Y2zcpTAAT28Iflzo2OpkAEIAoIAidS0eitkqqrAACyh+BQpFZABRKEmoJQADDxAANzhfYAATZFAN-gQMCJAAGmQAcny3LC8-CCVibSvkKAgAR0pgD6FkODIfogTQAqCaGgQcAFFbaIwjZCsBHvMqUKAgLLIohkZAAJmGVWY8MISKIORM9UazWQrTinW6yB6Fjsg0xI3Gk2mtwWS1W6y2O32h2Op0Elyu+kwD38z1eKO+vwg-0BzOgYIh1ChYBhcIJpMIHzAaIxuIcAP+koEwlE4kk9jweAA9I7kAB1KQAayEl0pTVyK12YBWB3+K2BmhWThcYGQgeQQVukulTx6xEGTGdxgAegB+B2Z91QL0+hp+5ArCzB4Ch1VQSPOa1peN3Tw+GUAFlxuszRFz+ZdADE4MBfMr-hBiI0JBBdj6xigK4pg0JgJoQBg0ShdvwlSArjHtr4pgDy7XgyVIeAo43A7jm4n3FK209O92Xb2807B8PR+bkBOp0gWdkHGFAQEEABaRcFGXVd1yND5Yx3IQ9wPXwj2mQEw0SEFz3BS8wGvVwLDvIIk2fJQek7dMv2zPMgA)